# Textview can't cast to widget

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator, android-holo-everywhere

I combine holoeverywhere with viewpagerindicator in my app, but I get this error:

```
12-16 16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-16 16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast
to org.holoeverywhere.widget.TextView 12-16 16:08:48.485:
E/AndroidRuntime(12366):    at
com.smart.tangsel.viewpagerindicator.TestFragmentAdapter.instantiateItem(TestFragmentAdapter.java:101)
12-16 16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):    at
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:832) 12-16
16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):  at
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:982) 12-16
16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):  at
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914) 12-16
16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):  at
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436) 12-16
16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):  at
android.view.View.measure(View.java:15193) 12-16 16:08:48.485:
E/AndroidRuntime(12366):    at
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
12-16 16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):    at
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574) 12-16
16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):  at
android.view.View.measure(View.java:15193) 12-16 16:08:48.485:
E/AndroidRuntime(12366):    at
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
12-16 16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):    at
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310) 12-16
16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):  at
android.view.View.measure(View.java:15193) 12-16 16:08:48.485:
E/AndroidRuntime(12366):    at
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
12-16 16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):    at
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
12-16 16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):    at
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
12-16 16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):    at
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574) 12-16
16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):  at
android.view.View.measure(View.java:15193) 12-16 16:08:48.485:
E/AndroidRuntime(12366):    at
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
12-16 16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):    at
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310) 12-16
16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):  at
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2217)
12-16 16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):    at
android.view.View.measure(View.java:15193) 12-16 16:08:48.485:
E/AndroidRuntime(12366):    at
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1850) 12-16
16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):  at
android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1102)
12-16 16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):    at
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1275)
12-16 16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):    at
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000) 12-16
16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):  at
android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4216)
12-16 16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):    at
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
12-16 16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):    at
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555) 12-16
16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):  at
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525) 12-16
16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):  at
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
12-16 16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):    at
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 12-16
16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):  at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 12-16
16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):  at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 12-16 16:08:48.485:
E/AndroidRuntime(12366):    at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794) 12-16
16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):  at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 12-16
16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):  at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 12-16 16:08:48.485:
E/AndroidRuntime(12366):    at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
12-16 16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):    at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556) 12-16
16:08:48.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12366):  at
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and this my code:

```
package com.smart.tangsel.viewpagerindicator;

import com.smart.tangsel.LoginActivity;
import com.smart.tangsel.UserFunctions;
import com.smart.tangsel.app.ContentActivity;
import com.smart.tangsel.app.ContentCommentActivity;
import com.smart.tangsel.app.DetailLaporanActivity;
import com.smart.tangsel.app.SplashTangsel;
import com.smart.tangsel.app.WelcomeActivity;

import com.smart.tangsel.database_content.DatabaseHandler;
import com.smart.tangsel.database_content.Setting_App;
import com.smart.tangsel.R;

import org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import org.holoeverywhere.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TabWidget;
import org.holoeverywhere.widget.TextView;

public class TestFragmentAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private static String[] titles = new String[] {
        "Mudah",
        "Capture",
        "Submit",
        "Share",
        "Mari berpartisipasi dalam Pembangunan Kota Tangerang Selatan melalui Smart Tangsel"
    };

    private static String[] desc = new String[] {
        "Hanya dengan 3 langkah mudah",
        "Adukan temuan anda akan Kerusakan Fasilitas, Kemacetan dan Penyakit Masyarakat lainnya di kota Tangerang Selatan dengan sangat mudah.",
        "Ketik langsung keluhan anda untuk Pemerintah Kota Tangerang Selatan.",
        "Bagikan keluhan anda ke Social Media yang anda miliki.",
        ""
    };

    private static int[] images = new int[] {
        R.drawable.startup1,
        R.drawable.startup2,
        R.drawable.startup3,
        R.drawable.startup4,
        R.drawable.smart_tangsel,
    };

    private final Context context;

    public TestFragmentAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    UserFunctions userFunctions;

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View v, Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return v.equals(o);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles[position];
    }

    public String versi_app(Context context){
        PackageInfo pInfo = null;
        try {
            pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

     String version;
    return version = pInfo.versionName;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return titles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
         View v = ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                .inflate(R.layout.info_update, null, false);

         TextView title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title_update);
         TextView desc_up = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.desc_up);
         ImageView description = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_update);
         Button btn_start_app = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_start_app);

         if(position==(getCount()-1)){
             btn_start_app.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             desc_up.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             btn_start_app.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() 
             {

                public void onClick(View v) 
                {                   

                    DatabaseHandler settingappDb = new DatabaseHandler(context);                
                    Setting_App setting_app = new Setting_App("infoupdate",versi_app(context));        
                    boolean stat= settingappDb.addsetting_app(setting_app);

                    if(stat){
                         userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
                        if(userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(context)){ 
                            context.startActivity(new Intent(context,SplashTangsel.class));
                        } 
                        else{
                            context.startActivity(new Intent(context,LoginActivity.class));
                        }
                     //   ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition (R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_left_out);
                        ((Activity) context).finish();
                    }



                }
            });
         }

         desc_up.setText(desc[position]);

         title.setText(titles[position]);
         title.setShadowLayer(1,1,1, Color.WHITE); 

     //    if(position==0)title.setText(titles[position]+versi_app(context));

         description.setImageResource(images[position]);

         //This is very important
         ( (ViewPager) container ).addView( v, 0 );

         return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View pager, int position, Object view) {
        ((ViewPager) pager).removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View view) {
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable p, ClassLoader c) {
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View view) {
    }


}
```

When I click error, it seem in part **TextView title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title_update);**

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

By the looks of things, you're using the standard Android `TextView` in your layout file instead of the custom `org.holoeverywhere.widget.TextView`

```
<org.holoeverywhere.widget.TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_update"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: thans for your answer, i will try :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the import

```
import org.holoeverywhere.widget.TextView;
```

and replace it with

```
import android.widget.TextView;
```

Comment: thans for your answer, i will try :)

Answer (score 0):

make sure you had import **org.holoeverywhere.widget.TextView**.like this

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.holoeverywhere.widget.TextView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */

private TextView mTvShow;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mTvShow = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.layout.main);
    mTvShow.setText("Hello");
  }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<org.holoeverywhere.widget.TextView
        android:id="@+id/holo_tv_show"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World, MyActivity"/>
</LinearLayout>
```